# Passing a partial Method as a parameter, join then run method

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

Apologies if this sounds complex my vocab isn't fully with me today.

I have an method where I want to use .click 
Example

```
middle.click();
```

But I also have another

```
end.click();
```

What if  I want to pass either "middle" or "end" as a parameter, is it possible to do so

```
MethodGo(string usedforSomethingElse, Func<string> thisMethod)
{
     thisMethod.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would have to look more like this:

```
MethodGo(string usedforSomethingElse, ISomeObjectWithClickMethod thisObject)
{
     thisObject.click();
}
```

Or, you could do this:

```
MethodGo(string usedforSomethingElse, Func<string> thisMethod)
{
     thisMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace Student
        {
            public interface IMyClick
            {
                string click();
            }
        }
    --------------------------

        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace Student
        {
          public  class Middle : IMyClick
            {

                public string click()
                {
                    return "Middle Click";
                }
            }
        }

    ---------------------------
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Student
    {
     public class End :IMyClick
        {
            public string click()
            {
                return "End Click";
            }
        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Student;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IMyClick m1 = new Middle();

            IMyClick e1 = new End();

            string result = MethodtoGo(m1);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();

        }

        static string MethodtoGo(IMyClick cc)
        {
             return cc.click();
        }
    }
}
```

in the above code now you can pass the Middle  or End class instance as both are implementing the same interface.
 string result = MethodtoGo(m1);
The MethodToGo has one parameter of type interface, that mean any class that is implementing the interface can be pass as input to the method.

hope this helps.